# In the Doctor Who universe, what are the differences between Biblios, Carsus and “The Library” libraries

Tags: doctor-who

In the [List of Doctor Who planets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Doctor_Who_planets), there are three planets that have similar libraries:

- Biblios
- Carsus
- The Library

What are the physical differences among the planets? And what are the differences in content/knowledge that can be found in each one?

Answer (score 2):

## Biblios

[Biblios](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Biblios) was a library planet which collected all the known data of the universe except for weapons.

It was curated by robot librarians.

It first appeared in the Comic *[War of the Words](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/War_of_the_Words_(comic_story))*.

## Library of Carsus

The [Library of Carsus](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Library_of_Carsus) was the largest repository of knowledge in the universe.

It was curated by a Time Lord and friend of The Doctor, [Professor Rummas](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Rummas).

It first appeared in the novel *[Spiral Scratch](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Spiral_Scratch)*.

It is a very large pentagonal building on the planet of [Carsus](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Carsus), but the planet itself is not entirely a library, unlike the other two.

## The Library

[The Library](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Library) was simply a planet-sized library containing every book ever written, and only books. No other medium of knowledge was present there.

It was curated by robotic drones driven by [CAL](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Charlotte_Abigail_Lux).

It first appears in the modern Doctor Who TV episode *[Silence in the Library](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Silence_in_the_Library_(TV_story))*.

---

## TL;DR

**Biblios** - Library Planet, all known data of the universe, except weapons.
**Library of Carsus** - Large Pentagonal-shaped Library, largest repository of knowledge in the universe.
**The Library** - Planet-sized Library, contains every book ever written.

Comment: "No other medium of knowledge was present there." Except human souls.

Comment: Well, the Vashta Nerada dealt with that ;)